# Qt quick how to connect signal and slots from different file

Tags: qt, qml

I'm new to QML.
I want to connect a signal from a .qml file to a slot in another .qml.
The problem is that I haven't instantiate the object in that file because I want to use a StackView in the main.qml to see on the screen the objects in that .qml files.

in main.qml I have:

```
    StackView {
        id: mStackId
        anchors {
            top: topSectionId.bottom
            bottom: parent.bottom
            left: parent.left
            right: parent.right
        }

        initialItem: homePage
    }

    Component {
        id: homePage
        Home {id: homePageObj}
    }

    Component {
        id: housePage
        House {id: housePageObj}
    }

    Component {
        id: createRoomPage
        CreateRoom {id: createRoomPageObj}
    }
```

where Home, House and CreateRoom are the .qml files I want to make to connect.
I've tried:

```
  Component.onCompleted:
    createRoomPage.newRoom.connect(homePage.createNewRoom)
```

where newRoom is the signal and createNewRoom is the slot, but Qt Creator gives me the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'connect' of undefined
```

I've also tried to use createRoomPageObj instead of createRoomPage and homePageObj instead of homePage but I get the error:

```
ReferenceError: createRoomPageObj is not defined
```

I've read I could use Connections, but documentation is not too clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a matter of wrong `Connections` usage, the `createRoomPage` simply is not instantiated. You need a backend which can do the logic and to which you can connect from the views.

In the simplest form, you can make a `QtObject`

```
QtObject {
    id: backend

    signal newRoom(name)
}

StackView {
    ...
}
```

You can use `backend.newRoom("Kitchen")` from the `CreateRoomPage`.

---

EDIT after question about persistence

You can also create the `QObject` as a singleton:

```
pragma Singleton

import QtQuick 2.4

QtObject {
    signal newRoom(name)
}
```

In this case the filename will determine the name to use in the rest of the program. So if naming above piece of code `Backend.qml`, you can use as follows:

```
Connections {
    target: Backend
    function onNewRoom(name) { .... }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. It works well for sending signal the problem now is the slot. I have used a Connections in the Home.qml
`Connections {
            target: backend
            function onNewRoom() {
                swipeViewId.createNewRoom()
                console.log("signal received")
            }`
the function createNewRoom() works well, but I've noted that the changes are deleted when I change page with StackView. How can I make changes permanent (can I create a file where save this changes)? (Sorry for having edited the comment so many times)

Comment: You can also add the desired properties to the `backend` object for persistency